# Javascript Leaflet function not returning a value (except when debugging)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm using Javascript in a pretty complicated Leaflet map page. I've written the following function to step through all the features in a layer and return the maximum value for a given feature property

```
function maxPropertyValue(myGeojson, propertyName) {
        var maxie = 0;
        var propertyValue = null;
        myGeojson.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            propertyValue = layer.feature.properties[propertyName];
            if (propertyValue > maxie) {
                maxie = propertyValue;
            };

        });
        return maxie;
    };
```

Elsewhere, in another function, I call it like this:

```
theMax = maxPropertyValue(precinctsShowing, "vTOT16");
```

(theMax is global, declared at the top of the script and initialized to equal 0).

When I call this function, it always (incorrectly) returns a value of zero. But when I *step THROUGH* this function in Firefox's Debugger, it always returns the correct value. Then again, if I step OVER this function in Debugger, it will always return zero. I've spent days trying to figure this out, without luck.

What would cause a function like this to work properly in Debugger, but not when running normally? This feels kind of like a variable scope problem, but I don't see how. This is actually my second approach to this task; in my first effort I inspected all the property values as the geoJson is being loaded (using onEachFeature); that also worked when stepped through in Debugger, but failed (i.e., the global variable retained its initial value) when run normally. Very weird.

I've proven to myself that this is not an asynchronous problem, because if I click on a feature in the layer (before the function is called by a radio button click) the popup shows the feature property in question. But then when I click the radio button to run the function, it fails (i.e., theMax = 0, its initial value)

Comment: How are you loading the GeoJSON? Via a HTTP GET, perhaps? I suspect the function is being called before the layer's features have loaded when you are not running under the debugger.

Comment: Yes, the GeoJSON is loaded; visible in the map, and other functions work perfectly with it. Just this one is hinky.

Comment: Add logging to see what's going on and try it in another browser, too.

Comment: Are you *sure* it's loaded *at the time this function runs*? This sounds like a typical asynchronous mistake.

Comment: Sadly, yes; I'm sure. When I set a break point in Debugger at the function call, I can wait a long long time, then step THROUGH the function, and it works, or step OVER the function and it fails.

Comment: I should add that the approach shown here is my second one. In a first approach I used onEachFeature to find the max value while adding the GeoJSON to the map. That approach worked internally to onEachFeature, but when the result was written to a global variable, again the value wasn't stored there. Feels like a weird scoping problem or something.

Comment: This could depend on how each layer is being called. I'd put a console log with the scope inside the test function.

Comment: Try not initializing Maxie see if it returns undefined...

Comment: You should give a link to where the problem can be seen ...